# How to get the scores in a long-format data for histogram in the repeated-measures design

Tags: r, histogram

I transformed my data from wide-format to long-format using `melt()`, and my long-format data (df) is shown, as follows:

```
Participant Tests Scores  
1 A 8  
1 B 7  
1 C 1  
1 D 6  
2 A 9  
2 B 5  
2 C 2  
2 D 5  
3 A 6  
3 B 2  
3 C 3  
3 D 8  
4 A 5  
4 B 3  
4 C 1  
4 D 9  
5 A 8  
5 B 4  
5 C 5  
5 D 8  
6 A 7  
6 B 5  
6 C 6  
6 D 7
```

How can I get all scores for `df$Tests[1]` (i.e., for each Participant in the Tests = A)?

Furthermore, in case I wish to plot the Histogram such as:

```
hist.TestA <- ggplot(df, aes(???)) + theme(legend.position = "none") + geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), colour="black", fill="white", binwidth = 1) + labs(x="Test A", y = "Density") + stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(???, na.rm = TRUE), sd = sd(???, na.rm = TRUE)), colour = "black", size = 1)
```

but I don't know what I write in the field "???" in the above syntax.

Thank you in advance.

Best.

Comment: `dplyr::filter(df, Tests == "A")` will give you all the rows where `Tests = A`. As far as the `ggplot` part goes, unsure what you're after so can't be of much help there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to get scores or just subsets of data given Test

```
data <- data.frame(
    Participant= c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
    Tests = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"),
    Scores = c(8, 7, 1, 6, 9, 5, 2, 5)
)

sub <- by(data = data, INDICES = data$Tests, FUN = c)
```

It's a bit unclear of what you try to do with `ggplot` but if you want to plot histogram for each Test can do like this:

```
hist(x = sub$A$Scores, freq = FALSE, xlab = "Scores", main = "Test A")
```

or with ggplot

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Scores, color=Tests, fill=Tests)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), position="identity", alpha=0.5, bins=10)
```

Simple ANOVA plots can be done as following:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Tests, y = Scores)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = "grey80", colour = "blue") +
  scale_x_discrete() + xlab("Treatment Group") +
  ylab("Dried weight of plants")
```

for more on ANOVA and plotting see [this tutorial](http://www.jason-french.com/tutorials/repeatedmeasures.html)

Comment: Aleh, when my data is a wide-format (each Test is a column), I can plot the histogram using this command:  

hist.A <- ggplot(df, aes(A)) + theme(legend.position = "none") + geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), colour="black", fill="white", binwidth = 1) + labs(x="A", y = "Density") + stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(df$A, na.rm = TRUE), sd = sd(df$A, na.rm = TRUE)), colour = "black", size = 1)  
I thought to do the same, but now applying ggplot for long-format data. However, to plot, I should inform the values (or scores) for each Test == A.

Comment: I'm still not really sure what exactly you are after. Snippets above will give you data for each test which can be ploted. In case you want data.frame can do like this `sub <- by(data = data, INDICES = data$Tests, FUN = data.frame)` in case you want something more advanced you can supply you own function to `by()`.

Comment: perhaps I wasn't clear to explain what I would like to do. Initially, I have that raw data as shown in my above question. From that raw data, I intend to do my stats analysis because it is a repeated-measure design and to run one-way repeated-measures ANOVA, I should transform my raw data from wide-format to long-format. So, since my data is in long-format, I just would like to plot the histogram as preliminary statistical analysis before I start to analyse it in repeated-measures.

Comment: Moreover, that command I mentioned in my comment runs well when my data is in wide-format because A is a column and R plot the entire column. However, when those scores are scrambled in long-format data, I need to indicate to R that it needs to get only scores from Test == A. If I can do it, probably I can use this command inside the function aes().

Comment: Rei I did some updates, check the link to a tutorial above.

Comment: I saw the link and it is very interesting for running ANOVA and repeated measures. However, if you have this kind of long-format data, where the columns are "scrambled" because of the ordering by Participant, it seems a little bit difficult to get all scores from the same Test there in order to plot that histogram. Since I have transformed the data format using melt (), I just would like to use that long-format data to plot it.