# Function for calculate quantile and qnorm for QQ plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data:

```
Subject Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4  
    1   8   7   1   6  
    2   9   5   2   5  
    3   6   2   3   8  
    4   5   3   1   9  
    5   8   4   5   8  
    6   7   5   6   7  
    7   10  2   7   2  
    8   12  6   8   1
```

mydata <- read.csv("myData.csv", header = TRUE)
mydataframe <- data.frame(mydata)

I did the following function to be applied to each column variable of my data frame, which contains 4 columns:

```
qqfunc <- function(df,df_var) {    
          y <- quantile(df$df_var, c(0.25, 0.75))     
          x <- qnorm( c(0.25, 0.75))       
          slope <- diff(y) / diff(x)      
          int <- y[1] - slope * x[1]      
          ggplot() + aes(sample=df$df_var) + stat_qq(distribution=qnorm) +   
          geom_abline(intercept=int, slope=slope) + ylab("QQ")    
}
```

When I run

```
qqfunc(mydataframe, Test1)
```

appears the Warning Message:

> Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_abline).

As result, the QQ Plot doesn't appear in pdf output file. I am not sure if the problem is in the parsing or in the function ggplot().

PS:
1. Curiously, if I run these following commands outside the function, it works:

```
y <- quantile(mydataframe$Test1, c(0.25, 0.75)) # Find the 1st and 3rd quartiles  
x <- qnorm( c(0.25, 0.75)) # Find the matching normal values on the x-axis
slope <- diff(y) / diff(x) # Compute the line slope
int <- y[1] - slope * x[1] # Compute the line intercept # Generate normal q-q plot   
ggplot() + aes(sample=mydataframe$Test1) + stat_qq(distribution=qnorm) + 
  geom_abline(intercept=int, slope=slope) + ylab("QQ Test1")
```

2.If I run these commands:

```
qqfunc <- function(df, df_var) {   
  y <- quantile(df[[df_var]], c(0.25, 0.75))   
  x <- qnorm( c(0.25, 0.75))  
  slope <- diff(y) / diff(x)  
  int <- y[1] - slope * x[1]  
  ggplot() + aes(sample=df[[df_var]]) + stat_qq(distribution=qnorm) + 
    geom_abline(intercept=int, slope=slope) + ylab("QQ")   
}
qqfunc(mydataframe, Test1)
```

Error message:

> Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x,  : 
>     object 'Test1' not found

FULL CODE:

```
library(Hmisc)  
library(ggplot2)  
library(boot)  
library(polycor)  
library(ggm)  
library(gdata)  
library(readxl)  
library(csvread)  
library (plyr)  
library(psych)  
library(mice)  
library(VIM)  
library(ez)   
library(reshape)   
library(multcomp)  
library(nlme)  
library(pastecs)  
library(WRS2)  
library(dplyr)  

mydata <- read.csv("mydata.csv", header = TRUE) # CSV  
mydataframe <- data.frame(mydata)  

y <- quantile(mydataframe$Test1, c(0.25, 0.75)) # Find the 1st and 3rd quartiles   
x <- qnorm( c(0.25, 0.75)) # Find the matching normal values on the x-axis   
slope <- diff(y) / diff(x) # Compute the line slope   
int <- y[1] - slope * x[1] # Compute the line intercept # Generate normal q-q plot   
ggplot() + aes(sample=mydataframe$Test1) + stat_qq(distribution=qnorm) + geom_abline(intercept=int, slope=slope) + ylab("QQ Test 1") 

qqfunc <- function(df, df_var) {     
         y <- quantile(df[[df_var]], c(0.25, 0.75))   
         x <- qnorm( c(0.25, 0.75))   
         slope <- diff(y) / diff(x)   
         int <- y[1] - slope * x[1]   
         ggplot() + aes(sample=df[[df_var]]) + stat_qq(distribution=qnorm) + 
           geom_abline(intercept=int, slope=slope) + ylab("QQ")   
}
qqfunc(mydataframe, Test1)
```

Comment: Can you share your data? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315885/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-r-data-on-stackoverflow

Comment: The problem seems to be `quantile(df$df_var`, ...)`. Try instead `quantile(df[[df_var]], ...)`.

Comment: Subject Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4  

1 8 7 1 6  
2 9 5 2 5  
3 6 2 3 8  
4 5 3 1 9  
5 8 4 5 8  
6 7 5 6 7  
7 10 2 7 2  
8 12 6 8 1

Comment: Rui, when I use those commands outside the function, they work well. However, I just would like to compile those commands into a function to avoid to write them for each column of my data frame

Comment: @Rei: you should add your data to your question, not the comment. Do read the link I posted

Comment: @Rui: Appears an error: Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x,  : 
  object 'column_variable' not found

Comment: @Tung: I inserted the data in the question.

Comment: @Rei: You need to use `dput` and add the output to your question

Comment: @Tung: I don't know how to use dput. I edited my question.

Comment: `dput(mydataframe)` or `dput(df)`

Answer (score 1):

Works with me. You should have followed my suggestion.
And the suggestion of @Tung to post a sample dataset. Since you have not, here is the complete working code.

```
library(ggplot2)

qqfunc <- function(df, df_var) {    
          y <- quantile(df[[df_var]], c(0.25, 0.75))     
          x <- qnorm( c(0.25, 0.75))       
          slope <- diff(y) / diff(x)      
          int <- y[1] - slope * x[1]      
          ggplot() + aes(sample=df[[df_var]]) + stat_qq(distribution=qnorm) +   
              geom_abline(intercept=int, slope=slope) + ylab("QQ")    
}  

set.seed(3551)    # Make the results reproducible
n <- 100
mydataframe <- data.frame(X = rnorm(n))

column_variable <- "X"

qqfunc(mydataframe, column_variable)
```

[image: qqplot]

Comment: I tested using df[ [df_var] ], but I failed and I received the following error message: 

Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x, : object 'Test1t' not found.

Comment: I didn't understand why you used these commands: set.seed(3551); n <- 100; mydataframe <- data.frame(X = rnorm(n)); column_variable <- "X";

Comment: I am aware that this data frame has a few number of scores. However, it worked using these commands aforementioned in my question outside the function. The problem I have found is parsing the arguments or ggplot inside that function. I tried to run your commands, but mydataframe <- data.frame(X = rnorm(n))  changes my data frame. My data frame has 4 columns.

Comment: `Test1` needs to be in quote `"Test1"`

Comment: @Rei 1) `set.seed` is to make the call to `rnorm` always produce the same random numbers. 2) I have created a data frame, not necessarily similar to yours, it only needs to have one column because you are just producing the qqplot of one column. Even if you want several qqplots, you will do them one at a time. To check whether the code works I only need one column.

Comment: @Rei Like @Tung says, the call should be `qqfunc(mydataframe, "Test1")`. This is **exactly** what I do in the **example** above.

Comment: Last question: Isn't it possible to have a compound y-axis label such as ylab (c("Q-Q Plot", df_var)) in order to distinguish among other Q-Q plots?

Comment: @Rei yes, it is. `ylab = paste("Q-Q Plot", df_var)` should do it.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, may you help me please in another post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972955/how-to-get-the-scores-in-a-long-format-data-for-histogram-in-the-repeated-measur

Comment: @Tung, may you help me please in another post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972955/how-to-get-the-scores-in-a-long-format-data-for-histogram-in-the-repeated-measur

Comment: @RuiBarradas, that code works very well. However, if my data has an additional column, which variable is called Timepoint like a repeated-measures design, how can I introduce that variable in that code?

Comment: qqfunc <- function(df, df_var, df_var1, label1) { 
  while (df[[df_var1]] == label1) {
  y <- quantile(df[[df_var]], c(0.25, 0.75)) 
  x <- qnorm( c(0.25, 0.75)) 
  slope <- diff(y) / diff(x) 
  int <- y[1] - slope * x[1] 
  ggplot() + aes(sample=df[[df_var]]) + stat_qq(distribution=qnorm) + 
    geom_abline(intercept=int, slope=slope) + ylab(paste("Sample: ", df_var)) + labs(title = paste("Q-Q Plot: ", df_var))
  }
}

qqfunc(mcdata_dataframe, "Outcome", "Timepoint", "T1")

Comment: // The idea is filtering the Outcome scores while the Timepoint == "T1" and then plot those Outcomes scores only.

For another Timepoint == "T2", the idea is calling the function as:

qqfunc(mcdata_dataframe, "Outcome", "Timepoint", "T2")

and so on...

Thanks, @RuiBarradas

Comment: @Tung, do you have any suggestion, please? Thanks you both!